# Eclipse XText Object Oriented Grammar

Tags: eclipse, antlr, xtext, xtend

I am a rookie in XText and have built my own scripting language but now I want to start to be able to add stuff like namespaces and new object creation from other classes that are imported and wondering if anyone knows of any open source projects I could potentially look at to use as an example. I've looked around and have not been able to come up with any examples that implement an object oriented grammar with scoping and other concepts which I'm trying to learn. 
Thanks. - Duncan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking for a similar project for many months without much success. I think the reason is that most Xtext projects use Xtend for the back-end. The projects I've looked at in some detail are
[coffee-script](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/coffeescript-eclipse) and [FJ-Eclipse](http://fj-eclipse.sourceforge.net/).

The best book on Xtext I've found is [Implementing Domain-Specific Languages with Xtext and Xtend](http://www.packtpub.com/implementing-domain-specific-languages-with-xtext-and-xtend/book). The book deals mainly with the front-end but also handles symbols, scoping and objects.

The two (non-xtext) books I use for insight on the back-end stuff are [Introduction to Compiler Construction in a Java World](http://www.cs.umb.edu/j--/) and [Modern Compiler Implementation in Java](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Modern-Compiler-Implementation-Andrew-Appel/dp/052182060X).

There are many Xtext based projects out there. Googling **grammar filetype:xtext** will throw up lots of nuggets.

Cheers, Steve

Comment: Thanks I got the book!